# Unable to find class, even though autoloader has loaded the file

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader

So I have a directory that mirrors my namespace structure.  The autoloader is correctly loading the file containing my class. the use clause is specifying the correct class with an alias.  Despite all of this, PHP says it cannot find the class.  I have traditionally not used namespaces, because this always happens to me. But I am trying to force myself to use good practice. So, I am here to try and understand why I can't get this to work.

I have checked that the autoloader has in fact loaded the file.  I have checked that the path used by the autoloader is correct.

my class file:

```
<?php
namespace classes\helpers\core_helper;

class core_helper
{


  public static function create_arg_pairs($arguments)
  {
  .....
  }


}//end core_helper


?>
```

My Main app file:

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", "1");

define('AUTH_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));

use classes\helpers\core_helper as hlpr;


function autoloader($class)
{

  if(require_once AUTH_ROOT.'/'.str_replace('\\','/',$class).'.php');

}
spl_autoload_register('autoloader');

......

$temp = explode("/", substr($path['path'], 1));
//get the controller
$contoller = strtolower(array_shift($temp));
//get the method
$method = strtolower(array_shift($temp));

$argArray = hlpr::create_arg_pairs($temp);


?>
```

The resulting error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'classes\helpers\core_helper' not
>   found in /var/www/html/auth/index.php:51 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in /var/www/html/auth/index.php on line 51

However I know that the file containing that class was loaded, so the correct namespace was passed to the autoloader and it was converted correctly to the correct path. So why can't I see the class?

Comment: "I know that the file containing that class was loaded"  How exactly do you know this?

Comment: You probably need to call the autoloader before the use statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By saying

```
namespace classes\helpers\core_helper;
```

and then

```
class core_helper
```

you are telling the system that your actual class is `classes\helpers\core_helper\core_helper`. I expect that what you really want is `namespace classes\helpers;`.

Comment: Ah, I now see. Thank you very much. I changed the namespace to classes\helpers
and this now works as intended,  Thank you for your assistance and patience.

Comment: For anyone else who might have come across this issue, my mistake was in believing that the autoloader was invoked when the use reserved word is used, passing the namespace and class name to the autoloader.  Clearly, the autoloader is invoked on classes access and the class name is derived and then the namespace prepended.  In my case, this means the class name appears twice, as it is already part of the namespace. I hope my explanation of my epiphany helps anyone else who find themselves with this issue.  Again thank you, Greg, for your answer and guidance.